# struct x86_hw_tss is different between 32bit and 64?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

From http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h?a=microblaze#L209 i saw this struct x86_hw_tss is defined in different way, depending on of 32 and 64 bit

How linux kernel handle this different?

I think this is something related to the cpu arch, but i would to know if somebody with more experience can give me some more deep information about this

Comment: As you can see, this difference is handled with #ifdef.

Comment: yes, i saw this is handled with #ifdef, but i would like to know why the kernel does this

Comment: Because the different CPU modes have different TSSes.

Comment: thanks for your answer, what is different in tss under 32 bit and 64 bit

Comment: @CL maybe is because the linux kernel in 64 bit mode, doesn't support hadware context switch as described on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_state_segment#TSS_in_x86-64_mode

Comment: The differences are shown in that header file.